# set the pgp signing marker to the top of the new message

Tags: gnus

I try to switch from notmuch mail to Gnus (since the notmuch setup is too komplex; keeping the tags synchronized across three devices is very hard; and due to work requirements I have to move messages with a specific tag to a specific folder; much too complex). In notmuch I wrote this little snippet to always sign messages with GnuPG:

```
(defun ck/sign-message ()
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (point-min))
  (search-forward "--text follows this line--")
  (end-of-line)
  (insert "\n")

  (mml-secure-message-sign-pgpmime))

(add-hook 'message-setup-hook 'ck/sign-message)
```

This ensures that the signing marker is always the first thing in the new message since `mml-secure-message-sign-pgpmime` searches for the first newline and then inserts the marker.

But since Gnus yanks the text after the message-setup-hook gets executed. I now end up with the signing marker after the quoted message.

Is there a hook that gets executed after the yanking? I could not find one, but maybe I’ve been overseeing it? If not: is there a different solution for this problem?

I’d like to have the marker directly below the `--text follows this line--` marker and the quoted text below.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out: there is another hook, the `gnus-message-setup-hook`. Documentation says:

```
Hook run after setting up a message buffer.
```

And this is also after the quoted message has been yanked.